# VPN in Ubuntu fails every time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, vpn, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to setup a vpn connection in Ubuntu 10.04 to use the service from relakks.com

I used the network manager to add the vpn connection and the settings are:

> Gateway: pptp.relakks.com
>   Username: user
>   Password: pwd
>
> IPv4 Settings: Automatic (VPN)
>
> Advanced:
>
> MSCHAP & MSCHAPv2 checked
>
> Use point-to-point encryption (security:default)
>   Allow BSD data compression checked
>   Allow deflate data compression checked
>   Use TCP header compression checked

The connection always fail, here is the syslog:

```
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop NetworkManager: <info>  Starting VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp'...
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 2064
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN service 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp' just appeared, activating connections
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin state changed: 3
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN connection 'Relakks' (Connect) reply received.
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop pppd[2067]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5//nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop pppd[2067]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop pppd[2067]: Using interface ppp1
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop pppd[2067]: Connect: ppp1 <--> /dev/pts/0
Jun 27 20:11:56 desktop pptp[2071]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Jun 27 20:11:57 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 1 'Start-Control-Connection-Request'
Jun 27 20:11:58 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:739]: Received Start Control Connection Reply
Jun 27 20:11:58 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:773]: Client connection established.
Jun 27 20:11:58 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 7 'Outgoing-Call-Request'
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:858]: Received Outgoing Call Reply.
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[ctrlp_disp:pptp_ctrl.c:897]: Outgoing call established (call ID 0, peer's call ID 1024).
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop kernel: [   56.564074] Inbound IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=93.182.139.2 DST=186.110.76.26 LEN=61 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=40460 DF PROTO=47 
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop kernel: [   56.944054] Inbound IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=93.182.139.2 DST=186.110.76.26 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=40461 DF PROTO=47 
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[callmgr_main:pptp_callmgr.c:258]: Closing connection (shutdown)
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[ctrlp_rep:pptp_ctrl.c:251]: Sent control packet type is 12 'Call-Clear-Request'
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[pptp_read_some:pptp_ctrl.c:544]: read returned zero, peer has closed
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pptp[2079]: nm-pptp-service-2064 log[call_callback:pptp_callmgr.c:79]: Closing connection (call state)
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pppd[2067]: Modem hangup
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pppd[2067]: Connection terminated.
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop NetworkManager: <info>  VPN plugin failed: 1
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop NetworkManager:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp1, iface: ppp1)
Jun 27 20:11:59 desktop pppd[2067]: Exit.
```

Does someone can identify something in the syslog? I've been googling and reading about pptp but couldn't find anything about the error "read returned zero, peer has closed"

Comment: Did you select those options, or are they the defaults? (defaults worked beautifully for me with that release with a MS PPTP VPN)

Comment: I get the same errors with default settings.

Comment: Does this help: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-964255.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems. This will probably help:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10099463&postcount=3